# Windows RemoteApp deploying software updates, is there a better way?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

We provide an application as a service, over Windows RemoteApp. It's nearly impossible to deploy updates to the software, though, because if even a single user is online then the file is in-use and cannot be replaced.

Is there some way to make this possible or easier? If it were possible, I'd be deploying probably 2-3 updates per day. As it is, I sometimes have to go all week without deploying one.

Answer (score 2):

You could package the application up as [App-V](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/virtualization/app-v.aspx) . Citrix XenApp Application Isolation would probably do it too, but then you'd have to pay for Citrix licensing as well.

Your desired end-state is actually making 2-3 times daily updates to a provided application? Wowsers. Edit- I wonder if you'd do better to write this as a web application; that might make you more nimble/agile (tm), and it might help decouple your application logic so that you can do updates this rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to how you are packaging your application you could look at using a cluster of terminal servers on the back end.

Route all new sessions to a single node, wait for the old sessions to die off and then update the now unused node. Rinse and repeat.